# FCM Checking if property is nil (node.js)

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm currently setting up FCM using node.js.

If the message is an image, then it has the property imageUrl. I want to check if the message.imageUrl is nil, and if so that means the message is a text; if message.imageUrl exists, then the message is an image and I configure the body of the notification accordingly.

My question is how would I check if message.imageUrl = nil so I can set the body of the notification to either include the message text (if message.imageUrl is nil), or 'image' (if message.imageUrl != nil). I've included the whole function at the bottom, but the portion I'm specifically concerned with is the notification property of the notification variable, which I've enclosed with astersisks.

I'm fairly new to FCM (and also coding) so I'm not too familiar with this format of code. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
exports.observeMessages = functions.database.ref('/conversation_messages/{topicId}/{messageId}')

  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

    var topic = context.params.topicId;
    var messageId = context.params.messageId;
    var message = snapshot.val();

    return admin.database().ref('/conversations/' + topic).once('value', snapshot => {

      var conversation = snapshot.val();  // This gives us the conversation name

        return admin.database().ref('/users/' + message.senderId).once('value', snapshot => {

          var user = snapshot.val();

          var notification = {
            **notification: {
              title: conversation.conversationName,
              if (message.imageUrl == nil) {
                 body: user.username + ': ' + message.text
              } else {
                 body: user.username + ': image'
              }
            },**
            apns: {
              payload: {
                aps: {
                  sound: 'default'
                }
              }
            },
            data: {
              conversationId: topic
            },
            topic: topic
          };

          admin.messaging().send(notification)
            .then((response) => {
              // Response is a message ID string.
              console.log('Successfully sent message:' + notification + 'to topic: ' + topic, response);
              return response
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log('Error sending message:', error);
              throw new Error("Error sending message");
            });

      })

    })

  })
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I've edited the question so it's hopefully clearer now. Sorry about that!